# Identify differences with the previous record (by date)

Tags: sql, firebird, window-functions

I am implementing a kind of history trail along the lines of the 'slowly changing dimensions' pattern.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
create table ITEMS
(
  UID integer not null,
  REF varchar(20),
  TITLE varchar(100),
  DESCRIPTION varchar(1000),
  AUTHOR integer,
  ITEM_ID integer,
  VALID_FROM timestamp,
  VALID_TO timestamp,
  constraint PK_ITEMS_0 primary key (UID)
);
```

I have two triggers, a before insert that populates the UID field (surrogate key) and conditionally sets the ITEM_ID (natural key) and timestamp fields.

A before update trigger creates a new record (which thereby runs the before insert trigger) and copies the existing values to it. The actual insert will then overwrite the existing values if the user has changed something.

I haven't included the triggers here to keep the question short, but can do if it is better?

The record containing the latest 'version' has the VALID_TO timestamp set to NULL.

I can obtain the history for a given item using a query like:

```
select REF, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ITEM_ID, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO
 from ITEMS
 where ITEM_ID = 21
 order by VALID_FROM desc
```

This works very well, however I would like to extend this query so I can see which field(s) have changed. In this example it will only be REF, TITLE and DESCRIPTION that can change, but a more generic query would be good.

I think that this can be done using LAG, for example like the following:

```
select REF, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ITEM_ID, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO,
  iif (DESCRIPTION is distinct from lag(DESCRIPTION) 
    over (order by VALID_FROM asc), 
    'Desc Changed', '') 
from ITEMS 
where ITEM_ID = 1
order by VALID_FROM desc
```

But would welcome any better ideas. Ideally, I would like to have a query that did this, but if a stored procedure is better then that is also okay.

I am currently using Firebird 2.5.5 but could upgrade to 3.0.0 if need be.

Comment: You are right, with Firebird 3.0 this can be solved using `lag()`

Comment: Thanks, Firebird 3.0 installed and I plan to start working through the windowing examples.

Comment: I have achieved the basic functionality I was looking for with lag(), but I think this requires a stored procedure because I need to iterate over the columns in the table to see which one has changed.